# Getting win32 messages from Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow of UWP app windows

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I'm trying to get Pointer Win32 messages of a specific window, by a hook on `WH_CALLWNDPROC`, `WH_CALLWNDPROCRET` and `WH_GETMESSAGE`.

I use `SetWindowsHookEx` in a c++ dll to hook and receive messages.

```
unsigned long processID = 0;
unsigned long threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &processID);

g_hhkGetMsg = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE,
    GetMsgProc,
    g_hinstDLL,
    threadID);
```

This works for many windows, but not for `CoreWindow` of UWP windows.

Each UWP app window has a structure like this: [image: UWP window structure]

Hooking to ApplicationFrameWindow works correctly, but hooking to `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow` does not work. (`SetWindowsHookEx` shows success, but I don't get any messages in the callback)

However, **Spy++** is able to capture the messages from the `CoreWindow`. (The `CoreWindow` receives WM_POINTER messages, so I need to subscribe to that window)

Thinking the issue might be on my code, I also tried the open source tool [*MyLiteSpy*](https://github.com/yinkaisheng/MyLiteSpy) to see if that can capture messages from the CoreWindow. It can't capture anything, just like my sample code. (But MyLiteSpy is able to get messages from ApplicationFrameWindow of the same UWP app, and so can my code and Spy++)

[image]

Interestingly, [this (old) blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2007/01/16/spy-internals/) about Spy++ says that they use the same three hooks as me and MyLiteSpy, but it's getting messages that my code can't receive.

What is the difference here? Any idea why this is happening?

(Is Spy++ using hooks other than the three mentioned? The blog post is written in 2007, so things might have changed)

Comment: Spy++ has an embedded application manifest and is digitally signed. Does your code (or MyLiteSpy)?

Comment: @IInspectable No, mine is not digitally signed (in fact I'm running it from inside the Visual Studio), and I don't think MyLiteSpy has one either. However why would a digital sign or something in manifest affect win32 hooks? Is such dependency documented anywhere? And if true, any idea on how can I test this hypothesis?

Comment: you need have in manifest [`disableWindowFiltering`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sbscs/application-manifests)

Comment: @rbm: So a digital signature is not required, just the application manifest (containing the `disableWindowFiltering` element)?

Comment: @IInspectable - digital signature may be need if inject dll to protected process say. not test this. but without `<disableWindowFiltering>true</disableWindowFiltering>` process simply not view uwp windows (say `EnumWindows` skip this windows) so i guess, not test for hook, that `disableWindowFiltering` here play key role

Comment: @RbMm Huh, so without disableWindowFiltering the app can see the ApplicationFrameWindow but not the CoreWindow? Interesting. I also took a look at Spy++ manifest and it does have disableWindowFiltering set to true. Will try to add this to my manifest and see what happens. Just to make sure, I'm gonna need to add this to the manifest of the dll file, is that correct?

Comment: you need it how minimum add this to exe manifest , from which (process) you call `SetWindowsHookEx`. are this need in dll - not sure. faster that no. but will be nobad if you add it to dll manifest doo

Comment: yes, *spyxxhk_amd64.dll* not containing manifest. only *spyxx.exe* itself. you can copy it manifest (partially or full) to your exe

Comment: @RbMm I tried adding `disableWindowFiltering` to MyLiteSpy's executable (using Resource Hacker), but it did not work. Still not able to get messages from CoreWindow, but able to get for other window handles of uwp app. Also [here](https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/general-programming-and-reversing/177183-basic-intermediate-techniques-uwp-app-modding.html) it says that dlls don't need a digital signature to be injected to UWP apps. So if that's true, that's not the problem either.

Comment: *Still not able to get messages from CoreWindow* - but this is because your dll fail to load in uwp process

Comment: @RbMm Are there any indicators anywhere on why the dll is failing to load? I probably should retry this with my custom small dll, not MyLiteSpy's hook. (P.S. Spy++ from vs2017 is able to receive messages from CoreWindow of calculator on my PC)

Comment: sorry, i mistake. spyxx got messages from calculator. but it dll loaded not inside calculator but in *ApplicationFrameHost.exe*

Comment: check in spy to which process belong window - if to *ApplicationFrameHost.exe* this is ok and you can get messages for it, if for appcontainer (uwp) process - you (and spy++ too) fail here

Comment: @RbMm It seems that the root window is ApplicationFrameHost.exe, but the CoreWindow child window is the real exe process (onenoteim.exe for example), yet Spy++ succeeds in hooking into and getting messages from it.

Comment: the Spy++ can not got messages from child window (which in uwp process) too. because load dll in uwp process fail. on every message in uwp process called `LoadLibrary` for your (or spy++) dll. and this call is fail with error access denied

Comment: @RbMm Spy++ succeeds getting the messages on my machine, as shown in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cn0KE.png Maybe it uses a different method to retrieve them then?

Comment: are spy dll loaded in process ? can test for *Calculator.exe* ? and which version of spy++ you use ?

Comment: @RbMm I tried, and Spy++ can capture messages from Calculator.exe process (which owns the CoreWindow) as well. But I'm not sure how to check if and which dll is loaded in that process, can you elaborate?

Comment: @RbMm https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfhZC.png

Comment: i check this with self debugger, you can use say sysinternals tools procexp64.exe - what is spy++ version ? can you upload your spy++ build (spyxx_amd64.exe, spyxxhk_amd64.dll) i test it

Comment: @RbMm Spy++ version 15.00.27729 (x64). I'll try using procexp64.exe and will let you know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185600/discussion-between-rbmm-and-mahdi-ghiasi).

Comment: @IInspectable - i mistake, for load dll to windows store app digital signature is required, or we got error `STATUS_SYSTEM_NEEDS_REMEDIATION` from `ZwCreateSection` inside `LoadLibrary`

Answer (score 5):

windows of class *Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow* is usually immersive windows. for be able enumerate such, top level, windows, we need have [*disableWindowFiltering*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sbscs/application-manifests) in manifest. it disables window filtering so you can *enumerate* (via [`EnumWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows)) immersive windows from the desktop. but say direct call to `FindWindowW(L"Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow", L"Start");` - not fail even without *disableWindowFiltering* in manifest. however this part is only related to visibility  immersive windows, via [`EnumWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows), for your application.

another task set [`WH_GETMESSAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) hook for such windows. problem here that this windows usually belong to Windows Store app (AppContainer ) process.

> *Windows Store app development*: If *dwThreadId* is zero, then window hook DLLs are not loaded in-process for the Windows Store app
>   processes and the Windows Runtime broker process unless they are
>   installed by either *UIAccess* processes (accessibility tools).

so we need have or `uiAccess` set to true in manifest (say `<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true" />`) or not 0 for `dwThreadId` in call [`SetWindowsHookEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw). the `dwThreadId` we can got via [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid)

the [`WH_GETMESSAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) hook is always in process hook. so if we call it for another process - hook procedure must be located in dll, which will be loaded to target process. and here is main problem - how load dll to Windows Store app (AppContainer ) process.

i check this with self simply dll - try set hook for `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow::Calculator` window. the call for `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, ..)` is ok, and in *Calculator.exe* called `LoadLibraryExW` for my dll, but this call fail inside [`NtQueryAttributesFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/devnotes/ntqueryattributesfile) with error `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`. ok, Appcontainer is very restricted process, so i try change security descriptor on my dll. set it to `"D:P(A;;FA;;;BA)(A;;FXFR;;;WD)(A;;FXFR;;;AC)S:P(ML;;NW;;;LW)"` (give full access to Builtin (local ) administrators and read-execute access to all applications running in an app package context (`SDDL_ALL_APP_PACKAGES` - `"AC"`) and Everyone (`"WD"`). with this `LoadLibraryExW` go forward, but anyway fail in call [`ZwCreateSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwcreatesection) for my DLL with code `STATUS_SYSTEM_NEEDS_REMEDIATION` (`C000047EL` - *An error in a system binary was detected*) after which is `LdrAppxHandleIntegrityFailure` called (exported function from *ntdll.dll*)

[image]
[image]

so for load DLL to Windows Store app (Appcontainer) it must be signed. from kernel side call-stack is next

```
CI!KappxpNotifyNonPackagedFile
CI!KappxNotifyIntegrityFailureInPackagedProcess
CI!CipReportAndReprieveUMCIFailure
CI!CiValidateImageHeader
nt!SeValidateImageHeader
nt!MiValidateSectionCreate
nt!MiCreateNewSection
nt!MiCreateImageOrDataSection
nt!MiCreateSection
```

interesting that if check fail *CI.DLL* inside `KappxpNotifyNonPackagedFile` write file name and hash to registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\StateChange` - `BinaryName` (`REG_SZ`) and `BinaryHash` (`REG_BINARY`)

[image]

in case Spyxx - it use signed dll - *spyxxhk[_amd64].dll* - this dll (if allow all app packages access to it) is loaded to process ok. so potentially *Spy++* can collect messages from Appcontainer apps too. but in my research *Spy++* call `SetWindowsHookExW` at begin with `dwThreadId` set to zero. as result *spyxxhk[_amd64].dll* will be not injected to Windows Store apps. need every time use not 0 *dwThreadId* and have special security descriptor on dll.