# How can I get windows that are not even listed with EnumWindows() API?

Tags: windows, winapi

The EnumWindows() API is used to perform a specific action on all windows in the currently running system.
However, even though a ‘window’ clearly exists, there are cases where no information about ‘that’ window can be confirmed.

For example, the Start menu window that appears by pressing the 'Windows key' on the keyboard, the Game Manager window that appears by pressing the 'Windows key' + 'G', or the alarm menu window in Windows 10 or later.

These windows are the ones that the user can visually see and are known to be the same windows as actual application windows.

However, these windows do not seem to be identified by the simple EnumWindows() API I am using, nor by other functions.

Also, I know that the 'Band' of these windows is different from the default application depending on the window 'Band' added in Windows 8 or higher.

However, I don't know if these windows cannot be checked simply because their 'Band' order is higher than that of regular applications.

Because another Windows test tool I created had a UI_ACCESS property with a higher z-order band than the default application, I was able to access the window with a simple API like EnumWindows().

Therefore, I don't think the problem is that there are windows that I can't access (or are not listed in) because the window 'Band' values are different.

Do you have any good ideas for controlling these 'hidden' windows?

I would like to list or control all open Windows windows on the system. There seems to be a hidden window in addition to the windows returned by the basic API. I don't know how to approach them.

Comment: The question starts out asking about enumerating windows but ends with "controlling" windows.  The only supported way to control other windows is "UI Automation."  Also, I'm unclear what you mean by "z-order band."  The z-order determines which windows occlude others when they overlap on the virtual desktop.  But it sounds like you may be using "band" to refer to integrity levels?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "hidden windows" or "band", talking about Start menu or XBox Game. Use this official tool https://accessibilityinsights.io/ and hover over these windows and you'll see they are not hidden at all. They do disappear quickly when they lose focus so can be hard to spot.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy - op mean [`CreateWindowInBand`](https://blog.adeltax.com/window-z-order-in-windows-10/) and `ZBID`

Comment: you need have `<disableWindowFiltering xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2011/WindowsSettings">true</disableWindowFiltering>` in manifest

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53897370/6401656

Comment: @RbMm: Oh, goody, another undocumented API.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy this is already from win 8 or 8.1, so near 10 years. Solution for question is very simply - add **disableWindowFiltering**  to manifest. The `FindWindowW` work even without it

Answer (score 0):

EnumWindows calls the callback function for each *top-level* window.  It does not iterate through child windows (with certain exceptions).

[In places, the Windows API documentation can be ambiguous about whether owned windows are top-level windows. This ambiguity stems from the fact that the API uses a single field for both parent and owner windows (since you can have only one at a time).  The documentation doesn't always distinguish between parent and owner and sometimes uses "parent" to refer to either.
Likewise, some of the APIs for accessing the "parent" of a window actually reference either the parent or the owner.  In the comments, @Johnathan Potter assures us that owned windows are indeed top-level windows.]

A menu (possibly even the Start menu) is often implemented as a popup window, which it typically an owned window.

EnumWindows enumerates windows that currently exist.  Some popup windows persist in a hidden state when not needed.  Others are destroyed when not needed and may be recreated later if they're needed again.  So it's possible you're not seeing a window because it doesn't exist at the time your program is enumerating them.

Though the documentation for EnumWindows starts with the claim that the function enumerates "all top-level windows," the end of that page qualifies it to "only top-level windows of desktop apps" (since Windows 8).  Perhaps the windows you're trying to access do not belong to desktop applications.  An nowhere does it mention the window filtering that @RbMm says you must disable.

Windows have "integrity levels" that prevent lower integrity processes from sending messages to higher integrity windows.  That shouldn't affect enumeration of windows, but it could affect "controlling" them.

Comment: Popup windows / owned windows are top-level windows, and EnumWindows will pick them up.